# PIL: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: [picturename.jpg]

Tags: python, windows, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm coding a loop that takes screenshots and save the image with the same name as the previously one. The problem is that after a random number of iterations the program is aborted with the following error:

```
C:\Folder>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    screen_record()
  File "test.py", line 19, in screen_record
    printscreen.save(img_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2004, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'screen.jpg'
```

What could be the problem? I appreciate any support

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

def screen_record():

    keyboard = Controller()

    img_name = 'screen.jpg'

    while(True):

        printscreen =  ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,385,697))

        printscreen.save(img_name)

        img_rgba = cv2.imread(img_name,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)            

        cv2.namedWindow('window', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow('window', img_rgba)

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

screen_record()
```

Comment: That's an odd way of doing things... try moving `cv2.namedWindow()` out of the loop. Try running the loop just with the `ImageGrab.grab()` and nothing else in the loop. Try not saving and re-reading the file and just displaying what you grabbed. Try saving the file with name just `g-XX.jpg` where XX is a random number so you don't get permission issues. Just some ideas

Comment: @MarkSetchell Great tips! Following your recommendations my issue has been resolved. I'm posting the final code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Final code:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

def screen_record():

    keyboard = Controller()
    cv2.namedWindow('window', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    while(True):

        printscreen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 385, 697)))          
        RGB_img = cv2.cvtColor(printscreen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        cv2.imshow('window', RGB_img)

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

screen_record()
```

Comment: Well done, and thank you for sharing back with the SO community. Good luck with your project and come back if you get stuck again - it's free